# Is it possible to change the color of the name of a discord.py bot in code?

Tags: discord.py

I have been searching and can't seem to find a way to change the color of the discord bots itself name within the code. Like if I have a bot name Color Bot and someone calls !function1 I can have the bot have a red name but if they call !function2 the bot will have a blue name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In discord, the color depends on the color of the highest role the bot has. We will just have to change the color of the bot's role to change its color.

```py
@bot.command()
async def change_color(ctx, color: discord.Colour):
    role = ctx.guild.self_role
    if role is None:
        return await ctx.send('i dont have a default role')
    await role.edit(colour=color)
    await ctx.send('changed my color')
```

Note: This will only work if your bot has permissions to edit this role, it needs to have a higher no color role to edit this role.

References:-

- [`self_role`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.self_role)
- [`Colour`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Colour)
- [`Role.edit`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=role#discord.Role.managed)